# Not a managed type: class com.mycompany.onlineshop.entities.FirstName

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to display a custom object "FirstName" in the userController class. Basically I want it to return just the first name of the customer_id it gets but It is throwing an error of

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.mycompany.onlineshop.entities.FirstName
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:229) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:179) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:162) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:281) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:326) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

FirstName.java

```
public class FirstName {
    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public FirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

FirstNameRepo.java

```
@Repository
public interface FirstNameRepo extends JpaRepository<FirstName, Long> {
    @Query("select first_name from users_table where customer_id = ?1")
    FirstName getFirstNameofUser(long customer_id);
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private FirstNameRepo firstNameRepo;


    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return this.userRepo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/firstName/{id}")
    public FirstName getUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") long userId){
        return this.firstNameRepo.getFirstNameofUser(userId);
    }
}
```

I am beginner in Java Springboot, please go easy if I missed something. I am planning to add more properties to the FirstName but for simplicity sake I only have first name in it.

Comment: Why do you need the `FirstName`-class, anyways? Just save it as a `String`.

Comment: I'm planning to add more properties to the FirstName object like a surname maybe and for simplicity

Comment: If it is a part of another entity, you need to annotate `FirstName` with `@Embeddable`. If it should be a table on its own, use `@Entity`. However, `FiratName` might not be an appropriate class name if you want to add more properties.

Comment: I agree the naming is bad. However, it should return {firstname: "tommy"}, it is not a database entity, nor is it embedded in another object. It's just an object that should be returned.

Comment: It will not be embedded in another object, it would be embedded in the database.

Comment: Does it need to be? I just want to return the first name from the users_table based on the id, that's all.

Comment: You should put the query in the `UserRepo`, then and change it to `select new(your.package.FirstName(first_name) from users_table where customer_id = ?1`.